# How long do Spring 3 MVC session variables live?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, session-variables

I am trying to implement a type of client-side paging, where I only display X records at a time, then when the client wants to see more data I display the next X records and so forth. To do this I am trying to use a session variable, but every time I examine its value it is empty. I don't really know all that much about Spring MVC so any help would be appreciated:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/rest/da")
@SessionAttributes({"sessionRowKey"})
public class DAController {
    /**
     * Default constructor for DAController
     */
    public DAController() {
    }

    /**
     *  Initialize the SessionAttribute 'sessionRowKey' if it does not exist
     */
    @ModelAttribute("sessionRowKey")
    public String createSessionRowKey()
    {
        return "";
    }
```

Here I check if the value is empty, which is what I initialize it to, then set the value:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getModelData/{namespace}/{type}/{rowkey:[^\\.]*\\.[^\\.]*}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public
@ResponseBody
Map<String, Map<String, String>> getModelData(String namespace,
                                              String type,
                                              String rowkey,
                                              @ModelAttribute("sessionRowKey") String sessionRowKey,
                                              HttpServletRequest request)
{
    try 
    {
        ModelType modelType = ModelType.fromString(type);
        Model model;
        if(modelType == ModelType.STATISTICAL)  //page the data
        {
            //code abstracted
            List<KeyValue> records = results_arr[30].list();

            if(sessionRowKey.equals(""))
            {
                model = modelReader.readModel(namespace, modelType, rowkey);
                request.getSession().setAttribute("sessionRowKey", records.get(0).toString());
            }
            else model = modelReader.readModel(namespace, modelType, sessionRowKey);
        }
        else
        {
            model = modelReader.readModel(namespace, modelType, rowkey);
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        logger.log(Level.ERROR, "Error in DAController.getModelData: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Every time that I examine the session variable it is always "", How long does the session variable live?

Comment: The problem is not with the lifespan of the session variable.  Add some logging to see what methods are called when.  Off the cuff, I wonder if createSessionRowKey() is called multiple times.

Comment: Yes, try removing the createSessionRowKey() method and check for (sessionRowKey == null) instead of sessionRowKey.equals("").

Comment: @DwB A good idea, I added a log statement and the method only executed once.

Comment: @davidpeterson If I don't initialize the session variable I will get an error `HttpSessionRequiredException: Session attribute 'sessionRowKey' required - not found in session`

Comment: Is there an @SessionAttribute meta that you should use in the getModalData method (instead of the @ModelAttribute)?  My devbox is screwballed or I would be able to check.

Comment: @DwB No as far as I know you can only add `@SessionAttributes` to the controller definition

Comment: The @ModelAttribute annotation on the getModelData method's sessionRowKey parameter is definately wrong because the session attribute is not part of the model.  You might be able to confirm this by adding a BindingResult result parameter after the sessionRowKey parameter; but I'm not sure "not there" results in a binding error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the @ModelAttribute annotated parameter (sessionRowKey), use an HttpSession parameter and get the sessionRowKey using this parameter.  For example:

```
... HttpSession httpSession, ...

...

String sessionRowKey = (String)httpSession.getAttribute("sessionRowKey");

...
```

Note: the above is for Java EE 5 and above. For J2EE 1.4 and before use the HttpSession.getValue and HttpSession.setValue methods.

Comment: Thanks!, I will give this a shot and post back, I hadnt seen this method before.

Comment: you will need to set the session attribute as well using httpSession.setAttribute("sessionRowKey", someValue).

Comment: But be aware that this way you're creation a HttpSession that is expensive in terms of memory and making you're application stateful. You should use HttpSessions only when really required.